# Write a recursive function to list all paths of parts.txt

Tags: python-3.x, list, directory, os.walk

Write a function list_files_recursive that returns a list of the paths of all the parts.txt files without using the os module's walk generator. Instead, the function should use recursion. The input will be a directory name.
Here is the code I have so far and I think it's basically right, but what's happening is that the output is not one whole list?

```
def list_files_recursive(top_dir):
    rec_list_files = []
    list_dir = os.listdir(top_dir)
    for item in list_dir:
        item_path = os.path.join(top_dir, item)
        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            list_files_recursive(item_path)
        else:
            if os.path.basename(item_path) == 'parts.txt': 
                rec_list_files.append(os.path.join(item_path))
    print(rec_list_files)
    return rec_list_files
```

This is part of the output I'm getting (from the print statement):

```
['CarItems/Honda/Accord/1996/parts.txt']
[]
['CarItems/Honda/Odyssey/2000/parts.txt']
['CarItems/Honda/Odyssey/2002/parts.txt']
[]
```

So the problem is that it's not one list and that there's empty lists in there. I don't quite know why this isn't not working and have tried everything to work through it. Any help is much appreciated on this!

Comment: Please see [how do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Thanks for the How-To's, etc. I'll make sure to be aware of that and be courteous!

Comment: No problem. This update looks very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very close, but the issue is that `list_files_recursive`'s child calls don't pass results back to the parent. One way to do this is to concatenate all of the lists together from each child call, or to pass a reference to a single list all the way through the call chain.

Note that in `rec_list_files.append(os.path.join(item_path))`, there's no point in `os.path.join` with only a single parameter. `print(rec_list_files)` should be omitted as a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) that makes the output confusing to interpret--only print in the caller. Additionally,

```
else:
    if ... :
```

can be more clearly written here as `elif:` since they're logically equivalent. It's always a good idea to reduce nesting of conditionals whenever possible.

Here's the approach that works by extending the parent list:

```
import os 

def list_files_recursive(top_dir):
    files = []

    for item in os.listdir(top_dir):
        item_path = os.path.join(top_dir, item)

        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            files.extend(list_files_recursive(item_path)) 
            #     ^^^^^^ add child results to parent
        elif os.path.basename(item_path) == "parts.txt": 
            files.append(item_path)

    return files

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list_files_recursive("foo"))
```

Or by passing a result list through the call tree:

```
import os 

def list_files_recursive(top_dir, files=[]):
    for item in os.listdir(top_dir):
        item_path = os.path.join(top_dir, item)

        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            list_files_recursive(item_path, files)
            #                               ^^^^^ pass our result list recursively
        elif os.path.basename(item_path) == "parts.txt": 
            files.append(item_path)

    return files

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list_files_recursive("foo"))
```

A major problem with these functions are that they only work for finding files named precisely `parts.txt` since that string literal was [hard coded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding). That makes it pretty much useless for anything but the immediate purpose. We should add a parameter for allowing the caller to specify the target file they want to search for, making the function general-purpose.

Another problem is that the function doesn't do what its name claims: `list_files_recursive` should really be called `find_file_recursive`, or, due to the hardcoded string, `find_parts_txt_recursive`.

Beyond that, the function is a strong candidate for turning into a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) function, which is a common Python idiom for traversal, particularly for situations where the subdirectories may contain huge amounts of data that would be expensive to keep in memory all at once. Generators also allow the flexibility of using the function to cancel the search after the first match, further enhancing its (re)usability.

The [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) keyword also makes the function code itself very clean--we can avoid the problem of keeping a result data structure entirely and just fire off result items on demand.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
import os 

def find_file_recursive(top_dir, target):
    for item in os.listdir(top_dir):
        item_path = os.path.join(top_dir, item)

        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            yield from find_file_recursive(item_path, target)
        elif os.path.basename(item_path) == target:
            yield item_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(find_file_recursive("foo", "parts.txt")))
```